# Nodejs Separate player images

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

Hey i'm making an online game with nodejs. I am trying to make it so when someone joins, it runs Math.random and if its less than 0.5, they are an orange crab, else they are a red crab. Now this works correctly, except sometimes you can't see other people's image. I can't figure out exactly why this happens. Can someone take a look? I know its something simple. Here is my code:
Index.html:

```js
//var mongojs = require("mongojs");
var db = null;//mongojs('localhost:27017/myGame', ['account','progress']);

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/',function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(process.env.PORT || 2000);
console.log("Server started.");

var SOCKET_LIST = {};

var Entity = function(param){
 var self = {
  x:250,
  y:250,
  spdX:0,
  spdY:0,
  id:"",
  map:'forest',
 }
 if(param){
  if(param.x)
   self.x = param.x;
  if(param.y)
   self.y = param.y;
  if(param.map)
   self.map = param.map;
  if(param.id)
   self.id = param.id;  
 }
 
 self.update = function(){
  self.updatePosition();
 }
 self.updatePosition = function(){
  self.x += self.spdX;
  self.y += self.spdY;
 }
 self.getDistance = function(pt){
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(self.x-pt.x,2) + Math.pow(self.y-pt.y,2));
 }
 return self;
}

var Player = function(param){
 var self = Entity(param);
 self.number = "" + Math.floor(10 * Math.random());
 self.pressingRight = false;
 self.pressingLeft = false;
 self.pressingUp = false;
 self.pressingDown = false;
 self.pressingAttack = false;
 self.mouseAngle = 0;
 self.maxSpd = 10;
 self.hp = 10;
 self.hpMax = 10;
 self.score = 0;
 self.team = Math.random();

 var super_update = self.update;
 self.update = function(){
  self.updateSpd();
  
  super_update();
  
  if(self.pressingAttack){
   self.shootBullet(self.mouseAngle);
  }
 }
 self.shootBullet = function(angle){
  Bullet({
   parent:self.id,
   angle:angle,
   x:self.x,
   y:self.y,
   map:self.map,
   team:self.team,
  });
 }
 
 self.updateSpd = function(){
  if(self.pressingRight)
   self.spdX = self.maxSpd;
  else if(self.pressingLeft)
   self.spdX = -self.maxSpd;
  else
   self.spdX = 0;
  
  if(self.pressingUp)
   self.spdY = -self.maxSpd;
  else if(self.pressingDown)
   self.spdY = self.maxSpd;
  else
   self.spdY = 0;  
 }
 
 self.getInitPack = function(){
  return {
   id:self.id,
   x:self.x,
   y:self.y, 
   number:self.number, 
   hp:self.hp,
   hpMax:self.hpMax,
   score:self.score,
   map:self.map,
   team:self.team,
  };  
 }
 self.getUpdatePack = function(){
  return {
   id:self.id,
   x:self.x,
   y:self.y,
   hp:self.hp,
   score:self.score,
   map:self.map,
   team:self.team,
  } 
 }
 
 Player.list[self.id] = self;
 
 initPack.player.push(self.getInitPack());
 return self;
}
Player.list = {};
Player.onConnect = function(socket){
 var map = 'forest';
 if(Math.random() < 0.5)
  map = 'field';
 var player = Player({
  id:socket.id,
  map:map,
 });
 socket.on('keyPress',function(data){
  if(data.inputId === 'left')
   player.pressingLeft = data.state;
  else if(data.inputId === 'right')
   player.pressingRight = data.state;
  else if(data.inputId === 'up')
   player.pressingUp = data.state;
  else if(data.inputId === 'down')
   player.pressingDown = data.state;
  else if(data.inputId === 'attack')
   player.pressingAttack = data.state;
  else if(data.inputId === 'mouseAngle')
   player.mouseAngle = data.state;
 });
 
 socket.on('changeMap',function(data){
  if(player.map === 'field')
   player.map = 'forest';
  else
   player.map = 'field';
 });
 
 socket.emit('init',{
  selfId:socket.id,
  player:Player.getAllInitPack(),
  bullet:Bullet.getAllInitPack(),
 })
}
Player.getAllInitPack = function(){
 var players = [];
 for(var i in Player.list)
  players.push(Player.list[i].getInitPack());
 return players;
}

Player.onDisconnect = function(socket){
 delete Player.list[socket.id];
 removePack.player.push(socket.id);
}
Player.update = function(){
 var pack = [];
 for(var i in Player.list){
  var player = Player.list[i];
  player.update();
  pack.push(player.getUpdatePack());  
 }
 return pack;
}


var Bullet = function(param){
 var self = Entity(param);
 self.id = Math.random();
 self.angle = param.angle;
 self.spdX = Math.cos(param.angle/180*Math.PI) * 10;
 self.spdY = Math.sin(param.angle/180*Math.PI) * 10;
 self.parent = param.parent;
 
 self.timer = 0;
 self.toRemove = false;
 var super_update = self.update;
 self.update = function(){
  if(self.timer++ > 100)
   self.toRemove = true;
  super_update();
  
  for(var i in Player.list){
   var p = Player.list[i];
   if(self.map === p.map && self.getDistance(p) < 32 && self.parent !== p.id){
    p.hp -= 1;
        
    if(p.hp <= 0){
     var shooter = Player.list[self.parent];
     if(shooter)
      shooter.score += 1;
     p.hp = p.hpMax;
     p.x = Math.random() * 500;
     p.y = Math.random() * 500;     
    }
    self.toRemove = true;
   }
  }
 }
 self.getInitPack = function(){
  return {
   id:self.id,
   x:self.x,
   y:self.y,
   map:self.map,
  };
 }
 self.getUpdatePack = function(){
  return {
   id:self.id,
   x:self.x,
   y:self.y,  
  };
 }
 
 Bullet.list[self.id] = self;
 initPack.bullet.push(self.getInitPack());
 return self;
}
Bullet.list = {};

Bullet.update = function(){
 var pack = [];
 for(var i in Bullet.list){
  var bullet = Bullet.list[i];
  bullet.update();
  if(bullet.toRemove){
   delete Bullet.list[i];
   removePack.bullet.push(bullet.id);
  } else
   pack.push(bullet.getUpdatePack());  
 }
 return pack;
}

Bullet.getAllInitPack = function(){
 var bullets = [];
 for(var i in Bullet.list)
  bullets.push(Bullet.list[i].getInitPack());
 return bullets;
}

var DEBUG = true;

var isValidPassword = function(data,cb){
 return cb(true);
 /*db.account.find({username:data.username,password:data.password},function(err,res){
  if(res.length > 0)
   cb(true);
  else
   cb(false);
 });*/
}
var isUsernameTaken = function(data,cb){
 return cb(false);
 /*db.account.find({username:data.username},function(err,res){
  if(res.length > 0)
   cb(true);
  else
   cb(false);
 });*/
}
var addUser = function(data,cb){
 return cb();
 /*db.account.insert({username:data.username,password:data.password},function(err){
  cb();
 });*/
}

var io = require('socket.io')(serv,{});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
 socket.id = Math.random();
 SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;
 
 socket.on('signIn',function(data){
  isValidPassword(data,function(res){
   if(res){
    Player.onConnect(socket);
    socket.emit('signInResponse',{success:true});
    var playerName = ("" + socket.id).slice(2,7);
    for(var i in SOCKET_LIST){
  SOCKET_LIST[i].emit('addToChat',playerName + ': connected.');
  }
   } else {
    socket.emit('signInResponse',{success:false});   
   }
  });
 });
 socket.on('signUp',function(data){
  isUsernameTaken(data,function(res){
   if(res){
    socket.emit('signUpResponse',{success:false});  
   } else {
    addUser(data,function(){
     socket.emit('signUpResponse',{success:true});     
    });
   }
  });  
 });
 
 
 socket.on('disconnect',function(){
  var playerName = ("" + socket.id).slice(2,7);
  delete SOCKET_LIST[socket.id];
  Player.onDisconnect(socket);
  for(var i in SOCKET_LIST){
  SOCKET_LIST[i].emit('addToChat',playerName + ': disconnected.');
  }
 });
 socket.on('sendMsgToServer',function(data){
  var playerName = ("" + socket.id).slice(2,7);
  for(var i in SOCKET_LIST){
   SOCKET_LIST[i].emit('addToChat',playerName + ': ' + data);
  }
 });
 
 socket.on('evalServer',function(data){
  if(!DEBUG)
   return;
  var res = eval(data);
  socket.emit('evalAnswer',res);  
 });
 
 
 
});

var initPack = {player:[],bullet:[]};
var removePack = {player:[],bullet:[]};


setInterval(function(){
 var pack = {
  player:Player.update(),
  bullet:Bullet.update(),
 }
 
 for(var i in SOCKET_LIST){
  var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
  socket.emit('init',initPack);
  socket.emit('update',pack);
  socket.emit('remove',removePack);
 }
 initPack.player = [];
 initPack.bullet = [];
 removePack.player = [];
 removePack.bullet = [];
 
},1000/25);

/*
var profiler = require('v8-profiler');
var fs = require('fs');
var startProfiling = function(duration){
 profiler.startProfiling('1', true);
 setTimeout(function(){
  var profile1 = profiler.stopProfiling('1');
  
  profile1.export(function(error, result) {
   fs.writeFile('./profile.cpuprofile', result);
   profile1.delete();
   console.log("Profile saved.");
  });
 },duration); 
}
startProfiling(10000);
*/
```

```html
<style>
</style>
<div id="signDiv">
<center>
 <div>
 Jimothy-Online Beta
 </div>
 Username: <input id="signDiv-username" type="text"></input><br>
 Password: <input id="signDiv-password" type="password"></input>
 <div>
 <button id="signDiv-signIn">Log in</button>
 <button id="signDiv-signUp">Register</button>
 </div>
 </center>
</div>

<div id="gameDiv" style="display:none;">
 <div id="game" style="position:absolute;width:800px;height:500px">
  <canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="position:absolute;border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="ctx-ui" width="500" height="500" style="position:absolute;border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
  
  <div id="ui" style="position:absolute;width:500px;height:500px;">
   <button onclick="changeMap()" style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px">
    Change Map
   </button>
  
  </div>
  
 </div>
 
 <div id="belowGame" style="margin-top:520px"> 
  <div id="chat-text" style="width:500px;height:100px;overflow-y:scroll">
   <div>Welcome to Jimothy-Online Beta!</div>
   <div>------------------------------------------</div>
  </div>

  <form id="chat-form">
   <input id="chat-input" type="text" style="width:500px"></input>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>

<!--<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>-->
<script src="/client/socket.js"></script>
<script>
 // 
 var WIDTH = 500;
 var HEIGHT = 500;
 var socket = io();
 
 //sign
 var signDiv = document.getElementById('signDiv');
 var signDivUsername = document.getElementById('signDiv-username');
 var signDivSignIn = document.getElementById('signDiv-signIn');
 var signDivSignUp = document.getElementById('signDiv-signUp');
 var signDivPassword = document.getElementById('signDiv-password');
 
 signDivSignIn.onclick = function(){
  socket.emit('signIn',{username:signDivUsername.value,password:signDivPassword.value});
 }
 signDivSignUp.onclick = function(){
  socket.emit('signUp',{username:signDivUsername.value,password:signDivPassword.value});
 }
 socket.on('signInResponse',function(data){
  if(data.success){
   signDiv.style.display = 'none';
   gameDiv.style.display = 'inline-block';
  } else
   alert("Sign in unsuccessful.");
 });
 socket.on('signUpResponse',function(data){
  if(data.success){
   alert("Sign up successful.");
  } else
   alert("Sign up unsuccessful.");
 });

 //chat
 var chatText = document.getElementById('chat-text');
 var chatInput = document.getElementById('chat-input');
 var chatForm = document.getElementById('chat-form');
 
 socket.on('addToChat',function(data){
  chatText.innerHTML += '<div>' + data + '</div>';
 });
 socket.on('evalAnswer',function(data){
  console.log(data);
 });
 
 
 chatForm.onsubmit = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(chatInput.value[0] === '/')
   socket.emit('evalServer',chatInput.value.slice(1));
  else
   socket.emit('sendMsgToServer',chatInput.value);
  chatInput.value = '';  
 }
 
 //UI
 var changeMap = function(){
  socket.emit('changeMap');
 }
 
 
 
 //game
 var Img = {};
 Img.player = new Image();
 Img.player.src = '/client/img/player.png';
 Img.bullet = new Image();
 Img.bullet.src = '/client/img/bullet.png';
 
 Img.map = {};
 Img.map['field'] = new Image();
 Img.map['field'].src = '/client/img/map.png';
 Img.map['forest'] = new Image();
 Img.map['forest'].src = '/client/img/map2.png';
 
 var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
 var ctxUi = document.getElementById("ctx-ui").getContext("2d");
 ctxUi.font = '30px Arial';
 
 var Player = function(initPack){
  var self = {};
  self.id = initPack.id;
  self.number = initPack.number;
  self.x = initPack.x;
  self.y = initPack.y;
  self.hp = initPack.hp;
  self.hpMax = initPack.hpMax;
  self.score = initPack.score;
  self.map = initPack.map;
  self.team = initPack.team;
  
  self.draw = function(){ 
   if(Player.list[selfId].map !== self.map)
    return;
   var x = self.x - Player.list[selfId].x + WIDTH/2;
   var y = self.y - Player.list[selfId].y + HEIGHT/2;
   
   var hpWidth = 30 * self.hp / self.hpMax;
   ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
   ctx.fillRect(x - hpWidth/2,y - 40,hpWidth,4);
   
   var width = 48;
   var height = 48;

   if(self.team < 0.5)
    Img.player.src = '/client/img/crabo.png';
   else
    Img.player.src = '/client/img/crabr.png';
   
   
   ctx.drawImage(Img.player,
    0,0,Img.player.width,Img.player.height,
    x-width/2,y-height/2,width,height);
   
   //ctx.fillText(self.score,self.x,self.y-60);
  }
  
  Player.list[self.id] = self;
  
  
  return self;
 }
 Player.list = {};

  
 var Bullet = function(initPack){
  var self = {};
  self.id = initPack.id;
  self.x = initPack.x;
  self.y = initPack.y;
  self.map = initPack.map;
  
  self.draw = function(){
   if(Player.list[selfId].map !== self.map)
    return;
   var width = Img.bullet.width/2;
   var height = Img.bullet.height/2;
   
   var x = self.x - Player.list[selfId].x + WIDTH/2;
   var y = self.y - Player.list[selfId].y + HEIGHT/2;
   
   ctx.drawImage(Img.bullet,
    0,0,Img.bullet.width,Img.bullet.height,
    x-width/2,y-height/2,width,height);
  }
  
  Bullet.list[self.id] = self;  
  return self;
 }
 Bullet.list = {};
 
 var selfId = null;

 socket.on('init',function(data){ 
  if(data.selfId)
   selfId = data.selfId;
  //{ player : [{id:123,number:'1',x:0,y:0},{id:1,number:'2',x:0,y:0}], bullet: []}
  for(var i = 0 ; i < data.player.length; i++){
   new Player(data.player[i]);
  }
  for(var i = 0 ; i < data.bullet.length; i++){
   new Bullet(data.bullet[i]);
  }
 });
 
 socket.on('update',function(data){
  //{ player : [{id:123,x:0,y:0},{id:1,x:0,y:0}], bullet: []}
  for(var i = 0 ; i < data.player.length; i++){
   var pack = data.player[i];
   var p = Player.list[pack.id];
   if(p){
    if(pack.x !== undefined)
     p.x = pack.x;
    if(pack.y !== undefined)
     p.y = pack.y;
    if(pack.hp !== undefined)
     p.hp = pack.hp;
    if(pack.score !== undefined)
     p.score = pack.score;
    if(pack.map !== undefined)
     p.map = pack.map;
   }
  }
  for(var i = 0 ; i < data.bullet.length; i++){
   var pack = data.bullet[i];
   var b = Bullet.list[data.bullet[i].id];
   if(b){
    if(pack.x !== undefined)
     b.x = pack.x;
    if(pack.y !== undefined)
     b.y = pack.y;
   }
  }
 });
 
 socket.on('remove',function(data){
  //{player:[12323],bullet:[12323,123123]}
  for(var i = 0 ; i < data.player.length; i++){
   delete Player.list[data.player[i]];
  }
  for(var i = 0 ; i < data.bullet.length; i++){
   delete Bullet.list[data.bullet[i]];
  }
 });
 
 setInterval(function(){
  if(!selfId)
   return;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
  drawMap();
  drawScore();
  for(var i in Player.list)
   Player.list[i].draw();
  for(var i in Bullet.list)
   Bullet.list[i].draw();
 },40);
 
 var drawMap = function(){
  var player = Player.list[selfId];
  var x = WIDTH/2 - player.x;
  var y = HEIGHT/2 - player.y;
  ctx.drawImage(Img.map[player.map],x,y);
 }
 
 var drawScore = function(){
  if(lastScore === Player.list[selfId].score)
   return;
  lastScore = Player.list[selfId].score;
  ctxUi.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctxUi.fillText(Player.list[selfId].score,0,30);
 }
 var lastScore = null;
 
 document.onkeydown = function(event){
  if(event.keyCode === 68) //d
   socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'right',state:true});
  else if(event.keyCode === 83) //s
   socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'down',state:true});
  else if(event.keyCode === 65) //a
   socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'left',state:true});
  else if(event.keyCode === 87) // w
   socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'up',state:true});
   
 }
 document.onkeyup = function(event){
  if(event.keyCode === 68) //d
   socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'right',state:false});
  else if(event.keyCode === 83) //s
   socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'down',state:false});
  else if(event.keyCode === 65) //a
   socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'left',state:false});
  else if(event.keyCode === 87) // w
   socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'up',state:false});
 }
 
 document.onmousedown = function(event){
  socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'attack',state:true});
 }
 document.onmouseup = function(event){
  socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'attack',state:false});
 }
 document.onmousemove = function(event){
  var x = -250 + event.clientX - 8;
  var y = -250 + event.clientY - 8;
  var angle = Math.atan2(y,x) / Math.PI * 180;
  socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'mouseAngle',state:angle});
 }
 
</script>
```

Comment: You need a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @RyanZim I don't see how I can do this with an online game. You would need to download it and start it up in terminal and stuff. And if I make it not online, I could fix the error myself.

Comment: You could add screenshots then from different browser windows to illustrate the problem you're having.

Comment: It works fine for me. The only time I can't see the other player is if they're on a different map.